# How to get consistent date format DD/MM/YYYY in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

How do I get google sheets to consistently list date as DD/MM/YYYY ?

A cell formatted as DD/MM/YYYY displays that format but then the input window changes to MM/DD/YYYY.

The cell below is formatted using one of the standard options: `26/09/2008`

[image]

I'm trying to enter a date representing the 5th of October 2022 in DD/MM/YYYY and have it displayed in DD/MM/YYYY but it seems to have been interpreted as the 10th of May 2022 by the input window.

My PC's locale is set to a region that uses the DD/MM/YYYY format.

Answer (score 1):

To best avoid confusion whether `12/1` means 1st of December (month/day) or 12 January (day/month), make sure that **File > Settings > Locale** matches your real locale. The default locale is set based on your Google Account details. Your PC's locale setting does not come into play.

Another strategy is to use the [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard date format `yyyy-mm-dd` consistently everywhere.